# LlamaIndex node creation: how to keep track of the page number when creating the chunks/nodes ? (Python)

Tags: python, chunks, llama-index

I am building a query engine with LlamaIndex, based on a large database of PDFs, and I would like to be able to **retrieve the page number with the sources**.
The goal is to help the final user to look for more information in the original document. At this point I can only retrieve the filename + the text from the chunks that were selected to answer the query (I pass the filename in the metadata when creating the llama_index.Document, and I create 1 Document per PDF), but there is no way for a user to easily locate the chunk in a large PDF.

I saw that one method could be to create one Document per page when reading my PDFs (and just pass the page number to the metadata). But if I do that, then I don't understand how to create chunks that could have (for example) text coming from the end of page N and the beginning of page N+1.. And I don't want to end up splitting a paragraph just because the text is not on the same page.

I am currently creating the chunks with `TokenTextSplitter` and `SimpleNodeParser`.

*=> Is there a way to create chunks that can be spread over 2 consecutive pages of my documents, but still keep track of the page each chunk comes from ?*

Comment: did you have any luck with this? I have the same issue.